# A power allocation problem

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling, operations-research

Given $t > 0$, let the function $f : \Bbb R_0^+ \times \Bbb R_0^+ \times[0,1]\times[-1,0]\to \Bbb R$ be defined as

\begin{align}
&f(x,y,\rho_1,\rho_2)=\frac{(t+1)\left(x\left(1-\rho_1^2-\rho_2^2\right)+1\right)}{t+1-\left(\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x}\rho_1\right)^2}
\end{align}

I am interested in finding

$$\underset{x, y,\rho_1, \rho_2}{{\operatorname{argmax}}} f (x,y) \text{ such that the correlation coefficients } 0 \le \rho_1 \le 1, -1\le\rho_2\le 0, \text{ where } \rho_1^2 + \rho_2^2\le1 \text{ and } \rho_2 = -\frac{x+y + 2\sqrt{xy}\rho_1}{2\sqrt{tx}}$$

$0\le x\le x_1$, and $0\le y\le y_1$, where $x$ and $y$ are fixed.

---

**Motivation**

This is a power allocation problem for a telecommunication problem in which $t$ is the power of some noise which is fixed and non-negative, $x$ and $y$ are non-negative input powers subject to the power constraints $x_1$ and $y_1$, respectively. Here, it is assumed that $y$ is available for generating $x$. Therefore, the transmitter can correlate $x$ with $y$ to get some gains. $\rho_1$ is the correlation coefficients between some part of $y$ and $\rho_2$ is the correlation coefficients between another part of $y$ which has power $t$. Both $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ can be chosen by the user. We also know that the denominator is positive, this follows from the condition that $\rho_1^2+\rho_2^2\le1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the equation to single variable $x$ by :
$$u(x) = -\rho_2\times 2\sqrt{t x} -(1-\rho_1^2) x  = (\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x}\rho_1)^2$$.

Hence

\begin{align}
&f(x,y)=\frac{(t+1)\left(x\left(1-\rho_1^2-\rho_2^2\right)+1\right)}{t+1-u(x)^2}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
&f(x,y)=\frac{(t+1)\left(x\left(1-\rho_1^2-\rho_2^2\right)+1\right)}{t+1+(\rho_2\times 2\sqrt{tx} +(1-\rho_1^2) x)}
\end{align}

Hence $f(x,y) = f(x)$

Since $\rho_1,\rho_2,t$ are all fixed, the above is a function of one variable $x$. Now differntiate $f(x)$ and set to $0$ to obtain $x$ or check if the solution is at boundary of range of $x$.

If possible, tell me more about the physical significance or practical significance or operational significance of this problem you mentioned in the question more. Edit the question rather than commenting.

[EDIT]:
Since as per comments below $\rho_2$ also varies, we have:

\begin{align}
&f(x,y)/(t+1)=\frac{1+x(1-\rho_1^2) - x \rho_2^2}{1+x(1-\rho_1^2) + t+(\rho_2\times 2\sqrt{tx})}
\end{align}

But we need
$$-\rho_2\times 2\sqrt{t x} -(1-\rho_1^2) x  = (\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x}\rho_1)^2.$$
Since RHS is $\geq x \rho_1^2$
$\implies -\rho_2\times 2\sqrt{t x} \geq x \implies \rho_2 \leq -0.5\sqrt{x/t}$

Let $\rho_2 = -0.5\delta\sqrt{x/t}$, we get, for $\delta \geq 2\sqrt{\frac{t}{x}}$

\begin{align}
&f(x,y)/(t+1)=\frac{1+x(1-\rho_1^2) - 0.25 \delta^2 x^2/t}{1+x(1-\rho_1^2) + t-\delta x}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
&f(x,y)t/(t+1)=\frac{t(1+x(1-\rho_1^2)) - 0.25 \delta^2 x^2}{1+x(1-\rho_1^2) + t-\delta x}
\end{align}

Rest depends on relation between $x,t$, for example,
If  $\rho_2 = -0.5\delta\sqrt{x/t} \leq -1$ i.e.,$\sqrt{x/t} \geq 2$ i.e., $x \geq 4t \implies \rho_2 = -1$.

Solve the above equation range by range.

Use the below inequality: For $a>0,b>0,c>0,d>0$,
$(a-b)/(c-d) \leq a/c \iff c(a-b) \leq a(c-d) \iff -bc \leq -ad \iff b/d \geq a/c$

Let $\delta x-t \geq 0$,
since  in this case, $\frac{0.25 \delta^2 x^2}{\delta x - t} \geq t$ then optimum value is $f(x,y) t/(t+1) = t$ with optimum solution $x = \frac{2t}{\delta}$.
Now we need to workout the case $\delta x - t <0 \implies x < t$. So now the final solution is $x = \frac{2t}{\delta}$ under the condition $x \geq t$. Under this condition, if $x = \frac{2t}{\delta} > x_1$, by choosing $\rho_2 = -1$ i.e., $\delta = 2 \sqrt{t/x}$, we get $x = \frac{2t}{\delta} = \sqrt{tx} > x_1 \implies t > x$. Hence under the condition $x \geq t$, the solution is $x =\frac{2t}{\delta}$.

You need to work out the case $x_1 < t$.

Comment: Thanks Balaji. Note that the last equation that you wrote is still a function of $\tilde{P}_A$ because $\rho_{XS} = -\frac{\tilde{P}_A+\tilde{P}_X + 2\sqrt{\tilde{P}_A\tilde{P}_X}\rho_{XA}}{2\sqrt{T\tilde{P}_X}}$. @balaji-sb

Comment: No, for fixed $\rho_{XS}$ and $P_X$ values, $P_A$ gets automatically chosen to satisfy this equation. This is one way to interpret your question. Note first line in your question says fixed $\rho_{XA},\rho_{XS},T$

Comment: Check your problem from where you picked and update the question, if you do not agree with what i said.

Comment: Thanks, I see your point. But $\rho_{XS}$ and $\rho_{XA}$ are correlation coefficients that will also be chosen to optimize the problem!

Comment: Then write it as $f(P_X,P_A,\rho_{XS})$ rather than $f(P_X,P_A)$.

Comment: Pls edit the motivation and make it clear. You have said $N$ but there is no $N$ in your equations. You mentioned correlation coefficient but correlation coefficient of what ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I modified the problem statement and the motivation! Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: I have changed the name of the variables for simplicity!

Comment: Taking derivative with respect to $y$ of the cost function in the problem statement and setting it to zero results to $\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x}\rho_1=\sqrt{2+x(1-\rho_1^2)}$ but taking derivative with respect to $x$ of the cost function in the problem statement and setting it to zero gets too complicated to solve!

Comment: Hi, i updated my answer, check it out

Comment: Thanks, I see your point. But I think since $-1\le\rho_2\le0$, $\rho_2=-1$! Am I right here!?

Comment: In some case, yes. I have updated the answer. Take a look. If you are not able to complete the solution, ping in comments. I will try again.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and help. I do not follow why you choose $\delta\ge1$ because we have $-1\le\rho_2\le0$!

Comment: I think $0\le\delta\le1$! Am I right?!

Comment: No $\delta \geq 1$

Comment: I see your point, thanks!

Comment: I added optimal solution for a special case. Try the rest. If you find my answer useful, pls upvote.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to upvote, but it did not let me! I will accept your answer once I check it!

Comment: Sorry Balaji! I do not follow why $x\ge\frac{2t}{\delta}\Leftrightarrow\frac{0.25\delta^2x^2}{\delta x-t}$! because from the inequality that you provided $a\triangleq2t$, $b\triangleq x$, $c\triangleq\delta$, and $d\triangleq1$!

Comment: define $a = t(1+x(1-\rho_1^2)), c = 1+x(1-\rho_1^2), b = 0.25 \delta^2x^2, d = \delta x-t$ and apply the inequality on $f(x,y)t/(t+1)$.

Comment: From the inequality if $b/d \geq a/c$ then $f(x,y)t/(t+1)  = (a-b)/(c-d) \leq a/c$

Comment: $\frac{0.25 \delta^2 x^2}{\delta x - t} = b/d \geq a/c = t$ happens when $x \geq \frac{2t}{\delta}$

Comment: I see, so you solved the inequality $\frac{0.25\delta^2x^2}{\delta x-t}\ge t$ for $x$, which is correct if and only if $x\ge\frac{2t}{x}$!

Comment: But since the equation $0.25\delta^2x^2-\delta tx+t^2\ge0$ has only one root and $0.25\delta^2\ge0$ then $0.25\delta^2x^2-\delta tx+t^2\ge0$ is always correct! Am I right here!?

Comment: It seems so. So there is your optimum solution.

Comment: Thanks, can you please clarify what do you mean with “Solve the above equation range by range”?!

Comment: You should consider $\delta x-t\leq 0$ in which case $\rho_2 = 0$. Another case is when $x = \frac{2t}{\delta} > x_1$. i.e, the optimum solution $x=\frac{2t}{\delta}$ does not meet the constraint on $x$ i.e., $x \leq x_1$. For this case, fix $\delta$ to max value: $\delta = 2\sqrt{\frac{t}{x}}$. This gives $\sqrt{tx} > x_1$. You have consider this as second case. Good Luck !

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not still follow why I should consider $\delta x-t\le0$, and the other cases you mentioned above!

Comment: Here, I am looking for argmax$_{x,y,\rho_1,\rho_2}f(x,y,\rho_1,\rho_2)$ not the optimal value of $f(x,y,\rho_1,\rho_2)$!

Comment: while working out $\frac{0.25 \delta^2 x^2}{\delta x-t} \geq t$ we assumed implicitly $\delta x-t \geq 0$. So you need to workout the case $\delta x - t <0 \implies x < t$. So now the final solution is $x = \frac{2t}{\delta}$ under the condition $x \geq t$. Under this condition, if $x = \frac{2t}{\delta} > x_1$, by choosing $\rho_2 = -1$ i.e., $\delta = 2 \sqrt{t/x}$, we get $x = \frac{2t}{\delta} = \sqrt{tx} > x_1 \implies t > x$. Hence under the condition $x \geq t$, the solution is $x =\frac{2t}{\delta}$.

Comment: I edited the answer. Basically we have solved the problem for $x_1 \geq t$. You need to work out the case $x_1 < t$.

Comment: Thanks Balaji, we found the solution when $\delta x-t\ge0$, but $\delta x-t\ge0$ is not equivalent to $x\ge t$ therefore this does not mean that we found the solution when $x\ge t$! Can you please make it more clear?

Comment: $\delta \geq 1$

Comment: Correct, but $\delta=2$, $x=3$, and $t=5$, here $\delta x=6\ge t=5$ but $x\le t$!

Comment: Thanks Balaji, I see!

Comment: Point being if $x \geq t$ then $\delta x - t \geq 0$ for all $\delta \geq 1$ for which we found the solution. Infact $\delta \geq 2 \sqrt{\frac{t}{x}}$ also satisfies this inequality.

Comment: $\delta\ge2\sqrt{\frac{t}{x}}$ satisfies $\delta x -t\ge0$?

Comment: if $x \geq t$ then it satisfies

Comment: modified the range of $\delta$ in the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Balaji, let me think about this for a little bit. I will let you know if I have any questions! Also, if you upvote this question, I will get enough points to upvote your answer!

Comment: I will upvote the question if you add eloborate details on the problem statement and the variables involved. Basically a proper problem setting. If this is ur research and meant to be a  secret, let me know. I will upvote.

Comment: This is part of an example that I try to provide for a general problem that I studied! This is a telecommunication problem where x is the power of one cahnnel input, $y$ is the power of another cahnnel input. The channel input y is provided to generate the channel input x so it make x correlated to y so that it can get some gains!

Comment: I hope this was helpful! Let me know if you want to know more!

Comment: I have also modified the motivation part according to this discussion. I hope it was helpful!

Comment: upvoted your question. Good Luck ! Bye !

Comment: Thanks! I’ll go over everything again and see if I can solve the problem for the general case. I’ll ask you if I don’t understand any part of your answer! Thanks again fro your time and help!